# Why am I getting all of these compilation errors in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add this UI on top of my map in my app to show the current speed a driver is driving. I get these errors in main.m. Why, and how can I fix it?

> Use of undeclared identifier 'viewSpeed'
>   Instance method '-setViewSpeed:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
>   locationmanager.m
>   Expected ':'
>   Expected method body
>   Expected identifier or '('
>   Missing '@end'

```
#import "locationManager.h"

@implementation locationManager
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize fastView;

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation description);
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;

    BOOL newLocationIsValid = [self isValidLocation:newLocation witholdLocation:oldLocation];
    if(newLocationIsValid && oldLocation)
    {
        int distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
        if(distance >2 && distance<10)
        {
            [self.fastView setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i meters ", distance]];
        }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)errort
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

@end

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog (@"%s", __func__);
}
```

main.m

```
-(void)userDidLoagin
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [userMap release];
    [_Speed release];
    [viewSpeed release];
    [_fastView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [userMap release];
    userMap = nil;
    [self setSpeed:nil];
    [self setViewSpeed:nil];
    [self setFastView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: What @Abhi Beckert said. Also you're missing a few brackets at the end of `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.

Comment: -1 for just throwing a huge block of code without indicating which line of anything the error is on.

Comment: @borrrden sometimes the compiler doesn't make it easy to find the errors. I pasted his code into Xcode and got nowhere with the debugger, had to read it one line at a time to find the issue. +1 to compensate for your -1.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Seriously?  I did the same and the error showed the exact line just as I expected.  The `NSLog` line with 2 error and the final line with 1.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Wut? Did you also paste the methods he claims to be in main.m directly into main.m with no surrounding `@implementation` as implied by his question?  Sometimes, the compiler's error messages are incredibly vague because the code is really really broken.

Comment: You have `locationManager:` twice, once after `@end`.

Comment: @bbum no, I didn't need to because there is no bug in that part of the code. Everybody's gotta start somewhere. We should be helping him out instead of telling him to go away.

Comment: I was told Using  switching over to ARC would be better because  then you don't have to worry about alloc/releases. How could I go about doing this instead to create a UIlabel to show the speed of a moving vehicle

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Then you aren't actually testing the code in the same context as OP.  My suspicion is that OP is quite new to iOS development and copy-pasted some code without understanding either what it does or where it should go.

Answer (score 3):

Whoah.  You need to take two steps back and review the [basic architecture of iOS applications.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

If the code you claim to be in main.m really is in main.m, then your app is not structured correctly at all.   In fact, in just about all iOS applications, you should never touch the main.m file at all.   And those are obviously instance method implementations which means they should be in a class's @implementation.

Comment: I was told Using  switching over to ARC would be better because  then you don't have to worry about alloc/releases. How could I go about doing this instead to create a UIlabel to show the speed of a moving vehicle

Comment: bbum is right this code is all a mess. Start over with some basics and a book or tutorials. Learn to walk first, then run.

Comment: @user2570674 Simply switching to ARC isn't going to fix what appear to be serious structural issues in your code.  Do you really have methods implemented in your `main.m`?   In what class?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation description);

{
```

To this:

```
{

NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);
```

(note I moved it to after the `{` and removed `descirption`).

That will fix that error you're getting.

Comment: I guess you want to say `NSLog(@"Location: %@", [newLocation description]);` or just `NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);`

Comment: @vikingosegundo thanks I didn't spot that mistake in his code. Updated my answer.

Comment: Definitely a problem, but a minuscule one in comparison to the rest of the issues.

Comment: I was told Using  switching over to ARC would be better because  then you don't have to worry about alloc/releases. How could I go about doing this instead to create a UIlabel to show the speed of a moving vehicle

Comment: Yes, using ARC is a good idea. You should watch a bunch of WWDC session videos to learn how to use UILabel and GPS: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like viewSpeed isn't a property, because it is not synthesized and is not prefaced with self. or _ when it is used in dealloc. Therefore the method you are trying to call does not exist. Change that line to

```
viewSpeed = nil;
```

And it should fix your problem.

EDIT: Didn't see that viewSpeed was also undeclared. You need to declare it as an ivar or property. With that said, in the code you have posted you don't seem to use it anywhere, so why bother releasing it and setting it to nil? Your @end also seems to be misplaced, it is above the "locationManager:" method.

Comment: Goes beyond that; it looks like there are method definitions in main.m that are not actually in an @implementation.

Comment: I must have missed them -- I was going by the list of compilation errors. In retrospect, I think you're on the money with your answer though... compilation issues are the least of OP's problems.

Comment: I was told Using  switching over to ARC would be better because  then you don't have to worry about alloc/releases. How could I go about doing this instead to create a UIlabel to show the speed of a moving vehicle